# There being no atmosphere or being no atmosphere or no atmosphere

Tags: grammar

> 1.What is the result of there being no atmosphere on the moon?
>
> 2.What is the result of being no atmosphere on the moon?
>
> 3.What is the result of no atmosphere on the moon?

Which sentence is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

#1 and #3 are correct and equivalent

> What is the result of there being no atmosphere on the moon?
>   What is the result of no atmosphere on the moon?